# Discard runaway values from Distance measurement

Tags: c, mean, arduino-ide

I am trying to get better readings from my HC-SR04 Ultra Sound Sensor:
I am using the New.ping library so `sonar.ping_cm()`gets me the measured distance in cm.
My idea is to measure `X`times and calculate the mean value (`Mean_Value_1`).
The next step is to get all readings that are +/- 20% off `Mean_Value_1` --> kick them --> calculate the new mean value and return it --> (`return x_distance / new_count;`)

I am uploading the value to thing speak but with the following code I always end up with 'NAN' uploaded :-(

Here's the code:

```
float getAverage(int X) { 
float x_distance = 0,temporary,Mean_Value_1;
int i = 0, first_count = 0, new_count=0, values[]={};

for (i = 0; i < X; i++) {
    x_distance += sonar.ping_cm();
    values[first_count++] = x_distance;
    delay(100);
} 
Mean_Value_1 = x_distance / X;
x_distance = 0;
for (i=0; i<first_count; i++){
  temporary = (Mean_Value_1 - values[i])*100/Mean_Value_1;
  if (temporary < 20 && temporary > -20){
    x_distance += values[i];
    new_count++;
  }
}
return x_distance / new_count;
}
```

thanks for the comments so far.
can I change `values[]={}`to `values[X]?

Edit for clarification:
I tried just the following code and it worked

```
double getAverage(int X) {
double x_distance = 0;
int i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < X; i++) {
    x_distance += sonar.ping_cm();
    delay(100);
}
return x_distance / X;


}
```

so if I call in the loop `double distance = getAverage(1000);`i get a decent measurement.
everything after that doesn't work

Comment: `int values[] = {}`? How does that even compile? In any case you've got a zero-elements array there, so `values[first_count++]` has undefined behavior.

Comment: Use `double` rather than `float`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of `new_count`. I suspect you're dividing by zero

```
return new_count ? x_distance / new_count : -1; /* distance cannot be negative! */
```